# Query to add few fields in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
select 
    T0.DocDate as [GRPO Posting Date],
    T0.DocNum as [GRPO Num]
    ,T0.CardName 
from OPDN T0 
where 
    year(T0.DocDate) ='2016'
    and (dateadd(day, 1, T0.DocDate) in (
        select odln.DocDueDate 
        from odln 
        where year(DocDueDate) = '2016'
    )
```

This is my query which works fine.But I need to get fetch other information. I don't know how to add this to the existing query.

For e.g. apart from grpo posting date, GRPO Num, CardName, I need to fetch odln.docnum, odln.docduedate which I have using in sub query.

Please help me to amend this query or any new query with that requirements.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is an `INNER JOIN` to `odln`:

```
SELECT
    T0.DocDate AS [GRPO Posting Date],
    T0.DocNum AS [GRPO Num],
    T0.CardName,
    T1.DocNum,
    T1.DocDueDate
FROM OPDN T0
INNER JOIN odln t1
    ON DATEADD(DAY, 1, T0.DocDate) = T1.DocDueDate
WHERE
    T0.DocDate >= '20160101' AND T0.DocDate < '20170101'
    AND T1.DocDueDate >= '20160101' AND T1.DocDueDate < '20170101'
```

Note:

- Avoid using functions on columns in the `WHERE` clause as it makes your query non-SARGable. In your case, you can write

  ```
  YEAR(T0.DocDate) = '2016'`
  ```

  as

  ```
  T0.DocDate >= '20160101' AND T0.DocDate < '20170101'
  ```

Comment: when i run my query i am getting 1000 records but when i run your query i am getting 22892 records!!!!

Comment: If `OPDN` and `odln` has one-to-many relationship, that is expected. You just need to determine which of the duplicate rows you want to return.

Comment: Thank you so much i have understand will change accoring to it

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. Let me know how it went.